# React issue with composition - _constructComponentWithoutOwner

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and unable to figure out this - 
jsbin link - https://jsbin.com/fitepo/edit?js,output

```
class TodoItem extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <li> {this.props.todo.task} </li>
    );
  }
}

class TodoList extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="todo-list-container">
        <ul>
          {
            this.props.todos.map(item => {
              return (
                <TodoItem key={item.id} todo={item} />
              );
            })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When adding a todo I get this error -

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at new TodoItem (fitepo.js:89)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (unpkg.com/react@15.1.0/dist/react.js:5956)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (unpkg.com/react@15.1.0/dist/react.js:5938)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (unpkg.com/react@15.1.0/dist/react.js:5857)
    at Object.mountComponent (unpkg.com/react@15.1.0/dist/react.js:13194)
    at ReactDOMComponent._mountChildAtIndex (unpkg.com/react@15.1.0/dist/react.js:12138)
    at ReactDOMComponent._updateChildren (unpkg.com/react@15.1.0/dist/react.js:12054)
    at ReactDOMComponent.updateChildren (unpkg.com/react@15.1.0/dist/react.js:12014)
    at ReactDOMComponent._updateDOMChildren (unpkg.com/react@15.1.0/dist/react.js:7642)
    at ReactDOMComponent.updateComponent (unpkg.com/react@15.1.0/dist/react.js:7471)

When I remove the TodoItem and replace it with li inside the map function, it works fine.

Please help. I am a noob in react.

Comment: ^ the answer here solves your issue

Comment: thanks @aw04
I have been breaking my head over where my understanding could be wrong. You saved my time.